# Firebird dump tables

Tags: firebird, database-replication, dump, firebird-3.0

I have a database.gdb running with Firebird 3.0.

This database has two tables:

- Table1 and
- Table2.

Every day I add records to these tables and when I have finished my work I need to export the two tables to another newer database.

I need a procedure which dumps the two tables into a script so to import data in the newer database using the script.

I am only able to create a script of tables which have always the same number of records (no records added every day).

This script should include:

1. CREATE TABLE
2. Export all records procedure of the two tables

I do not need code but just a hint.  I will study how to write code by myself.

I have created a handmade script.

```sql
CREATE TABLE TABYEARS (
    ID     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    YEARS  INTEGER,
    /* Keys */
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE TABCODE (
    ID     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NAME   VARCHAR(50),
    CODE   VARCHAR(50),
    /* Keys */
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO TABYEARS (ID, YEARS) VALUES (1, 2021);
INSERT INTO TABYEARS (ID, YEARS) VALUES (2, 2022);
INSERT INTO TABCODE (ID, NAME, CODE) VALUES (1, 'Robert', '10');
INSERT INTO TABCODE (ID, NAME, CODE) VALUES (2, 'Paul', '87');
COMMIT;
```

I do not add records very often to these tables. The first one has just one record every year.

How to create (not manually) a script like this but regarding
two tables in which every day I add 50 records?

I can use FlameRobin or IBExpert or similar.

Comment: It is unclear what answer/information you're looking for. Please ask a clear and specific question. As an aside, if this is about transferring data between Firebird database, then you're probably better of using PSQL `EXECUTE STATEMENT .. ON EXTERNAL` from the new database selecting all the records from this staging database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could try using [FBExport](http://fbexport.sourceforge.net/fbexport.php) to generate the insert statement. However, that tool hasn't been maintained in a while (as far as I'm aware)

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I will export data in .csv format. I will copy newer database to my Directory, run the script to create tables and views and - using my program - import data from .csv file into the tables. It is manually...but it works and if there is not anything faster and better....

Comment: Why do you need it as a file ? Maybe you can run regular SQL `INSERT` but `on external connection` ? https://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html  Also look into `EXTERNAL TABLE`s - if your data formats are fixed than those would be exactly binary dumps. Could be faster than script-based imp/ex. Though, of cours,e much less flexible and arfuably more fragile.

Comment: Frankly, in your case i would rather add two-way information exachange, and into your tables i would add a clumn like "replication id", null by default. Whenever your accumulating database receive the data packet, it should generate a receipt conformation, as a packet ( replication-session-id; table name -> row id list; table-name - row id list; ...).  This packet should be moved backward to the original database, so the imported rows would be marked.  I would also add a "after-update" trigger that would nullify that column, marking the row for another replication.

Comment: Currently you just risk some replication packet being lost (failed to transfer, failed to import, data corrupt, whatever), and the source database won't know it has to make a second attempt on those. Basically you have to research the topic "database replication" as there are number of approaches, well-known pitfalls, etc.  https://firebirdfaq.org/faq249/  /  https://www.ibase.ru/d_repl/

Comment: An example of in-database one-direciton replication by means of `External Transaction`  (in Russian)

http://gsbelarus.com/gs/wiki/index.php/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%94_Firebird